# List all methods in COMobject

Tags: python, methods, win32com

Is it possible?

Something in the lines of :

```
import win32com.client
ProgID = "someProgramID"
com_object = win32com.client.Dispatch(ProgID)

for methods in com_object:
    print methods
```

I got the `com_object.__dict__`, which lists:

```
[_oleobj_, _lazydata_, _olerepr_, _unicode_to_string_, _enum_, _username_, _mapCachedItems_, _builtMethods_]
```

Most are empty, except:

- `_oleobj_` (PyIDispatch)
- `_lazydata_` (PyITypeInfo)
- `_olerepr_` (LazyDispatchItem instance)
- `_username_` (`<unknown>`)

But I don't know how to access anything on those types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just found how to get most of the methods:

Here's how:

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

ProgID = "someProgramID"
com_object = win32com.client.Dispatch(ProgID)

for key in dir(com_object):
    method = getattr(com_object,key)
    if str(type(method)) == "<type 'instance'>":
        print key
        for sub_method in dir(method):
            if not sub_method.startswith("_") and not "clsid" in sub_method.lower():
                print "\t"+sub_method
    else:
        print "\t",method
```

Here's a exemple output with `ProgID = "Foobar2000.Application.0.7"`

Output:

```
Playlists
    Add
    GetSortedTracks
    GetTracks
    Item
    Load
    Move
    Remove
    Save
Name
    foobar2000 v1.1.13
ApplicationPath
    C:\Program Files (x86)\foobar2000\foobar2000.exe
MediaLibrary
    GetSortedTracks
    GetTracks
    Rescan
Minimized
    True
Playback
    FormatTitle
    FormatTitleEx
    Next
    Pause
    Previous
    Random
    Seek
    SeekRelative
    Start
    Stop
ProfilePath
    file://C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\foobar2000
```

Comment: I tried this code with `Excel.Application` as `ProgId` and it doesn't seem to work (no attribute `_prop_map_get_`) on Python 3.3.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, know of a way to list all "program IDs" available? I'm trying to run a microsoft program with python but I don't know if it has a COM object

Comment: Any one found a way of doing this in Python3?

Answer (score 18):

For those who find [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27371403/4465708) not working (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127959/win32-dispatch-vs-win32-gencache-in-python-what-are-the-pros-and-cons) for the reasons) - there's still a way to get objects having a  `_prop_map_get_` attribute (a dict that holds object's fields as keys). You just have to create the main app object with `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch()`.

Here's a convenience function I wrote that lists fields and methods of a passed COM object created that way:

```
from inspect import getmembers


def print_members(obj, obj_name="placeholder_name"):
    """Print members of given COM object"""
    try:
        fields = list(obj._prop_map_get_.keys())
    except AttributeError:
        print("Object has no attribute '_prop_map_get_'")
        print("Check if the initial COM object was created with"
              "'win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch()'")
        raise
    methods = [m[0] for m in getmembers(obj) if (not m[0].startswith("_")
                                                 and "clsid" not in m[0].lower())]

    if len(fields) + len(methods) > 0:
        print("Members of '{}' ({}):".format(obj_name, obj))
    else:
        raise ValueError("Object has no members to print")

    print("\tFields:")
    if fields:
        for field in fields:
            print(f"\t\t{field}")
    else:
        print("\t\tObject has no fields to print")

    print("\tMethods:")
    if methods:
        for method in methods:
            print(f"\t\t{method}")
    else:
        print("\t\tObject has no methods to print")
```

For an Excel object created with `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")` its output would be:

```
Members of 'Excel.Application' (Microsoft Excel):
    Fields:
        ActiveCell
        ActiveChart
        ActiveDialog
        ActiveEncryptionSession
        ...
        Workbooks
        WorksheetFunction
        Worksheets
        _Default
    Methods:
        ActivateMicrosoftApp
        AddChartAutoFormat
        AddCustomList
        Calculate
        ...
        Union
        Volatile
        Wait
```

Comment: This worked for me on Python 2.7 - I just had to change the {method} syntax in the print statements to make it compatible.

Comment: This is a good answer but note that this will only work with the application object. If you want further objects and to stick with `win32com.client.Dispatch(ProgID)` method then you have to run the makepy.py file found at `win32com\client\makepy.py` a dialog will open up, select the appropriate library. See more info at https://www.pythonstudio.us/introduction-2/implementing-com-objects-in-python.html . Its the paragraph that starts with `In order to generate the Python files that support a specific COM object, ` . If you do this then you can now use `dir()` & go through all props and methods

Comment: All methods will be listed with `dir()` and then r/w properties are listed under `_prop_mat_put_` and read only props under `_prop_map_get_`.

Comment: This method is working for me. Is ther any way to print the signature of the method (argument type and number, return type)?

Answer (score -5):

To list the attributes of an object you can use the dir() function. This is a built in function of python and does not need to be imported.Try something like:

print dir(object)

To see the attributes of the object.

Comment: It doesn't work well with com objects. It list some stuff, but I know some others that aren't showing.